# Crystal Report to Excel format

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report 11. I want to export a Crystal Report to multiple excel sheets in a single excel file.

Comment: Nobody's your free labour here. Put in some effort and we'll help you =)

Comment: don't be defensive. phpdeveloper is trying to help you.

Comment: @phpdeveloper, you're right that he didn't put in alot of work.  But on the plus side, his question was clear and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.milletsoftware.com/Visual_CUT.htm is a 3rd party program that can do this.  You can use a command-line to export your .rpt to .xls and make a new tab for each grouping.
The instruction manual is free to download and can get you familiar with his system.